# Fisher–Yates shuffle Algorithm

Tags: random, shuffle

Can we reduce the no.of calls being made to rand(n) in Fisher–Yates shuffle Algorithm. If not, how do we know that the no.of calls we are making is reasonable.

Comment: Fisher-Yates works by making a series of random choices, with one object chosen with each choice. If you tried to get by with fewer choices, it wouldn't be Fisher-Yates any more.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we reduce the no.of calls being made to rand(n) in Fisher–Yates shuffle Algorithm

No

You want to select `k` points from array - there are `k` calls to `rand()`, up to `N-1`.

> If not, how do we know that the no.of calls we are making is reasonable.

Well, you supposed to know how many points you want to produce/permute, so this is how many calls to `rand()` you have to make